# Partial network fallout (Gmail, Facebook,…)

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, network-protocols

**Firefox and Google chrome are unable to connect to `gmail.com`, `facebook.com` and a few other random sites. Most sites still work.**

Error message from Firefox (14-10-2018 version):

> Secured connection failed Connection was re-initialised while loading the page

Error message from Google Chrome:

> This site is unreachable

Working properly on Internet Explorer (max. privacy settings & lower privacy settings)

**What i did to identify / attempt to solve the problem:**

- cleared all cookies, web data and passwords from all cookies related to "google" in Firefox
- put cookies on in internet explorer and Gmail worked correctly there turned all add-ons off
- attempted to connect to `gmail.com` using private mode (Firefox)
- disabled my anti-virus to rule out antivirus problems

**Useful information:**

- most sites are unaffected and can still be connected with
- Firefox was up-to-date days before the problem acquired. It is still up to date.
- Google Chrome is outdated by 2 years, and (while it was properly working) stopped working at the same time as Firefox
- Gmail services are all working correctly (G board)
- no new programs, add-ons or extensions were installed days prior, during or after the problem acquired
- Firefox and Google Chrome can connect to any Google site, except gmail.
- no changes were made in configurations of the browsers weeks prior to the problem & troubleshooting
- both Firefox and Google Chrome can connect to gmail using the same network and account on another device
- my OS is Windows 8.1. The working PC is using Windows 7.
- compared to the OS on the Windows 7 computer, this OS is more updated. Also, OS version/patch shouldn't be a problem for not being able to access a specific site on Firefox, right?
- someone else has the exact same issue on Windows 10

Out of ideas, do you have any possible solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This site can’t be reached: "mail.google.com is currently unreachable"](https://superuser.com/questions/1217257/this-site-can-t-be-reached-mail-google-com-is-currently-unreachable).  Based on the answers, it seems like an issue with your OS configuration, not that the websites have an incompatibility with clients that do support TLS v1.3.  You are likely using a proxy that doesn't support it, although both browsers, have supported it for 6 months.  You never noticed this issue since they were out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your browsers (Firefox and Google Chrome) were updated (without your knowledge) to use TLS 1.3 by default. To fix the issue, force the browsers to use a lower TLS version.

**Google Chrome:**

1. go to Chrome and search exactly: `chrome://flags`
2. search `tls`
3. change `TLS 1.3` from `default` to `disabled`

**Firefox:**

1. go to Firefox and search exactly: `about:config`
2. accept the risk
3. search `tls`
4. change `securtiry.tls.version.max` from `4` to `3`

Comment: Google (all Google websites) and Facebook both support TLS 1.3.

Comment: I am not actually wrong.  I just connected to both Facebook and Google using the current version of both Chrome and Firefox.  I verified the maximum version of TLS each browser would use would be TLS 1.3.

Comment: I checked both Facebook.com and Gmail.com with SSLabs and their servers both support TLS 1.3.  So the only explaination is your clients do not support it.  There could be many reasons for that, but my statement wasn't wrong, I typically don't say something, I can't support with facts.